# Problem with drawing circle in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, ios4

I am trying to draw a  circle using the following code.

```
 -(void)drawRect
{
  CGContextRef contextRef = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
  CGContextSetRGBFillColor(contextRef,1,0,0,1);
  CGContextFillEllipseInRect(contextRef, self.frame);

}
```

I am getting my circle as expected, but at the edges of the circle truncated/interrupted. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using self.bounds instead of self.frame. What class are you subclassing?
Maybe you have to use self.view.bounds or self.view.frame ?

Comment: I am using self.frame as the parameter